# How do I access a dictionary value from my html file using a filter custom template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-template-filters

I can't access a dictionary value declared in my views.py, from my .html file.

I've been trying to use the several previous threads about this for hours and I just can't see it. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

views.py

```py
def test(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    day = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    year = now.strftime("%Y")
    month = now.strftime("%m")

    context  = {
              "content": [day,year,month],
              "object_list": queryset     
             }
    return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

filter.py

```py
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter(name='get_item')
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

test.html

```html
{% load filtres_dictionary %}
{% with content.get_item.day as content.day %}

    <p>{{ content|get_item:content.day }}</p>

{% endwith %}
```

I am currently getting the following error message, and what I wanted to get is: 2019-06-13. Printed in my website.

VariableDoesNotExist at /test/
Failed lookup for key [day] in ['2019-06-13', '2019', '06']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above is *not* a dictionary value. It is a *list*. You can however access list elements through the *index*, like:

```
<p>{{ content.0 }}</p>
```

the line `{% with content.get_item.day as content.day %}` makes not much sense: you here seems to assign a non-existing value to a *hypothetical* subdictionary.

That being said, I'm not convinced that using a *list* is a good idea here. You in fact indeed better use a dictionary, like:

```
context = {
    'content': {
        'day': day,
        'month': month,
        'year': year
    },
    'object_list': queryset     
}
```

then you can access this in the template as:

```
<p>{{ content.day }}</p>
```

> **Note**: the `get_item` template filter you use here, is useful if the key itself is variable, in which case you can thus pass an arbitrary key. That is *not* the case here.